# Protecting Threads on a thru-axle dropout

Tags: through-axle, dropouts

My bike uses a thru axel and as I use an indoor trainer quite a bit, I remove the back wheel quite often. I'm concerned about the threads. If they get destroyed on the dropout nut, the manufacturer told me the bike is destroyed.

My bike is the [Canyon endurace cf sl 7 etap](https://www.canyon.com/en-de/road-bikes/endurance-bikes/endurace/cf-sl/endurace-cf-sl-7-etap/3365.html?dwvar_3365_pv_rahmenfarbe=GY%2FBK).

What's the best way to protect the threads on the dropout?

Comment: Not much to worry about. Torque to correct setting, regularly clean and reapply lube to reduce the wear. It will take ages to wear out an M12 thread. The only real danger is if you cross-thread it which is very hard to do with a thru axle

Comment: Nice, thanks for the response and also good to hear. Do you recommend a special lube or will any lube do?

Comment: Any lube for threads - does not matter if a dedicated bike grease or automotive lithium grease or similar. Not a chain lube and not a thread locker.

Comment: The biggest danger is if the threads have inadequate preload in use. Movement in the threads is the most likely way to wind up destroying it. All the thru-axle thread standards are big and robust with a lot of threaded contact area, so if they're properly lubricated and torqued then there's not any cause for concern even with frequent re-installations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a quick look at photos of the dropouts and the hanger for this bike. It looks like it's possible the threads in the frame may be replaceable (I'd be surprised if they weren't) even though they don't appear to be part of the derailleur hanger.

You can best protect your threads by making sure the threads in the frame and of the axle itself are clean and free from grit, and lightly lubricated with any bicycle grease, or indeed any grease that claims to be waterproof.

Meanwhile, I have sucessfully fixed damaged M12 thru axle threads with a helicoil in the past but there are no guarantees this is suitable for every situation.